# Android TextView append SpannableString forcing java.lang.RuntimeException on Nexus 7

Tags: android, textview, append, runtimeexception, nexus-7

I have a serious problem which crashes my app.

I'm loading some text in the app into a TextView. Some parts of this text are clickable and should call another activity - this works fine for most devices.
Unfortunatelly it does not work on Nexus 7 devices and I really don't know why.

This is the stacktrace I get from Google:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:197)
>   at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:111)
>   at android.widget.Editor$UserDictionaryListener.(Editor.java:3836)
>   at android.widget.Editor.(Editor.java:192)
>   at android.widget.TextView.createEditorIfNeeded(TextView.java:8475)
>   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3611)
>   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
>   at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:3277)
>   at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:3267)
>   [...some app methods but not relevant to this problem...]

The java code:

```
final String text = displayedText;
SpannableString link = makeLinkSpan(displayedText, new View.OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //call the activiy
    }
});

textView.append(link);
```

The stacktrace tells me to call Looper.prepare() but I don't know where...
I'm loading some data in an AsyncTask. A layout was inflated inside the doInBackground method and the textView is just a child of it. I don't see any reasson why this problem only affects my Nexus 7 users and not my devices. Even the emulator with Nexus 7 preset is working without any problem

Any Ideas how to solve this? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inflate layout on main thread. You can do this->

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Inflate layout & set textview's text here

        }
    });
```

Comment: Since I do not have a Nexus 7 and can't reproduce the issue myself I have to wait some time until I see if it works or not. ... If there is another way I would prefer the other one since I don't know how much this method reduces the ui thread's speed. Well - lets see tomorrow

Comment: Okay..But do you understand the root cause? Because thats more important, you can accept the answer once you test it

Comment: no, sorry. I don't know why inflating and edit this in ui thread should fix this problem :/

Comment: Because all the UI Related operations should be done on UI thread only & `doInBackground` always excutes on background thread, thats why it was giving you the erroor `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` whereas `onPostExecute` executes on UI thread

Comment: App is now online for several hours and there are no more crashes. Your solution works for me. Just inflate the layout in UI thread and load the data in a background thread. Thank you!